# getdate() in sql displaying date in a different format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-function

**This is not a question although, just a query.**

While I was playing with SQL queries, I found something I was unable to know how it was happening.

I used the following query:

```
select Replace(getdate(),'-','')
```

And I got a result like

```
May  9 2014  4:51PM
```

Now, I thought to change the query to:

```
Select REPLACE(Getdate(),'-','/')
```

or used any other character in place of '/', I got the same output.

Would appreciate if someone could explain how this was happening. And yes, one more thing, could you please guide me how to format the question too, since I know this question's gonna need formatting after I have posted it...:P

Comment: thanks @marc_s, i have now got how formatting was being done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace function has a definition as:

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

where

1. string_expression: Is the string expression to be searched.
2. string_pattern: Is the substring to be found.
3. string_replacement: Is the replacement string.

Now what's happening here is Getdate() returns current date as a `datetime` datatype which is implicitly converted to varchar or to say a string expression to evaluate the function. Try casting getdate() to varchar as below and you should get your confusion resolved:

```
select CAST( getdate() AS nvarchar(25))
```

You can read more about Implicit conversions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2):

REPLACE() function is converting datetime value to string representation of date

Comment: but, why replace function is displaying same result even when I am using a different character to replace '-'?

Comment: Because there are no `-` in it in the first place?

Comment: when we use this statement

select getdate(), we get '-' in its output

Comment: REPLACE() is a string function and returns a string value , whatever you do with GETDATE() inside REPLACE function is **STILL** a valid datetime value and gets converted to corresponding string representation

Comment: @vstandsforvinay - you're not comparing the same things. When you do `SELECT GETDATE()`, what's returned is still a `datetime` value and then **SSMS** has to convert that to a string to display it. It uses its default format. When you `SELECT REPLACE(GETDATE()...` then **SQL Server** is forced to convert the `datetime` into a `varchar()` and it uses *its* default format. SSMS and SQL Server itself disagree on what a sensible default format is.